# Why can some operators like '::', '.', '?:' not be overloaded in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, language-design

While operators like `+` , `-` , `*`... can be overloaded, operators like `?:`, `::`, `.` cannot be overloaded. Why is this?

Comment: Probably because it'd be super confusing.

Comment: Except perhaps for `.` which I think Bjarne himself wanted to make overloadable. [Here's a bit about that proposal](https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/02/a-bit-of-background-for-the-operator-dot-proposal-bjarne-stroustrup) - _"We tried to find a way to prevent a pointer (or reference) to the referred-to object to escape from the smart reference, but couldn’t find a simple way of guaranteeing that so we gave up, quoting “C++ protects against Murphy, not Machiavelli.”"_

Comment: You skipped the part that says "We ensured that you can define a matching set of smart . (dot), -> (arrow), * (dereference), and [] (subscript) operators with the relations they have for built-in types.". The point is not that it can't be done in current C++, but that it has been done (at least on paper) and he's describing the difficulties encountered and limitations to take into account.

Comment: Specifically, "so we gave up" is in regards to that particular safety check, not the proposal itself. The proposal exists and is complete.

Answer (score 1):

`::` works on namespaces and type names, you can't overload that because types aren't something you can return in C++.

`?:` could *possibly* be overloaded as long as you give up its short circuiting aspect, since you'd have to receive both branches as parameters. Not worth the drawback in my opinion.

`.` could definitely be overloaded, it has the same logic as `->` (with slightly different binding, of course). The reason why it's not is anyone's guess however.

Comment: Bjarne has stated that `?:` is not overloadable, because he couldn't initially come up with a syntax for that. And later he hasn't cared enough to revisit the design - because what would the use case be?